# How can I handle OFPT_ERROR: MeterModFailedCode.OFPMMFC_OUT_OF_BANDS error code?

Tags: sdn, openflow, openvswitch, meter

I have problem in Python-OpenFlow. And when I create MeterMod request to OVS switch it gets but return " OFPT_ERROR: MeterModFailedCode.OFPMMFC_OUT_OF_BANDS error code received ".
I want to know what this errors refers to and how solve the problem.

```
 meter_mod = MeterMod()
    meter_mod.command = MeterModCommand.OFPMC_ADD
    meter_mod.flags = MeterFlags.OFPMF_PKTPS
    meter_mod.meter_id = 5
    band = MeterBandDrop()
    band.length = 16
    band.rate = 300
    band.burst_size = 0
    meter_mod.bands = FixedTypeList(ListOfMeterBandHeader(items= band))

    event_out = KytosEvent(name=('kytos/of_l2ls.messages.out.'
                                     'ofpt_meter_mod'),
                               content={'destination': event.source,
                                        'message': meter_mod})
    self.controller.buffers.msg_out.put(event_out)
```